# Best approach to save many, Many to Many Relationship records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am parsing a excel and saving employees and projects raw data into normalized tables. I have 2 models

```
Excel Like
```

[image]

employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accesible :name. :salary, :band
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
end
```

Created a join table

```
employees_projects
```

Now I am doing something close to

```
Employee.transaction do
    1000.times do |i|
     emp = Employee.new(:name => 'Employee#{i}',
                       :salary => i * 1000,
                       :band => 'A')
     emp.projects.push(Project.find(i)) #the projects are already populated bfr this activity
     emp.save!
    end
end
```

**Please suggest some better way of saving the project association with employee in a single line**

Comment: Just to understand, you are parsing an Excel spreadsheet which lists the employee with a specific project? Is it one row per employee/project match? Just trying to better understand what the actual is that you are having? It seems like what you are doing is working...if this is a one time thing, why try to get the code all to one line?

Comment: @JasCav Updated the question with a Dummy excel,  this is the way it looks. First i am parsing Column E just to create projects table. Later when i am filling the employee table i parse the excel (2nd to 4rth row) and pull the project object from the data that is already populated in project and fill the Employee table.  This approach is working fine.  But need a good better approach to save this many-to-many relation as i find this code a bit cluttered and i am parsing 10,000 rows so performance is also a requirement.

Comment: Few notes: `has_and_belongs_to_many` is out of favor now, use `has_many` + `:through` option. Wrap your stuff in a transaction, speed has to increase significantly. Searching for a project just to populate `employees_projects` table with the already known project_id looks like a waste of resources/time - consider manual creation of records in `employees_projects`, w/o searching for the project (you'll need a model for the `employees_projects` table).

Comment: @jdoe i missed adding transaction in my question updated it as i am already wrapping things in transaction.  But i can give a thought about what other things you said

Comment: And of course use indices (aka indexes) for [groups of] "important" fields, not just for keys. Say, if you use validation of the `name` uniqueness, adding an index for the `name` field will lead to quicker creation/updating of your records.